# Is it possible to turn off pagination in the Android Jetpack Paging3-library to load all the data at once?

Tags: android, paging, android-jetpack, android-paging-library

There are 2 types of lists in my application. Shortlists should load instantly without pagination. Long lists must be loaded page by page. I would not like to write 2 different codes and I want to use the paging library in both cases by simply changing the parameters. How can I do that?

Comment: Add Variable page to your component and in first list fix page to 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the size of the initial load with `PagingConfig.initialLoadSize`.